# DebuggerTypeProxy for generic type hierarchy

Tags: c#, debugging, math.net, mathnet-numerics

I'm trying to write a debugger type proxy/surrogate for matrices and vectors in Math.NET Numerics, so the debugger shows more useful information (also in F# FSI). The type hierarchy is as follows:

- `Generic.Matrix<T>`
- `Double.Matrix : Generic.Matrix<double>`
- `Double.DenseMatrix : Double.Matrix`

### What works

Non-generic proxy with closed, generic type. It also works the same way if instead of `Matrix<double>` the constructor would accept a `Double.Matrix` or a `Double.DenseMatrix`.

```
public class MatrixSummary
{
    public MatrixSummary(Matrix<double> matrix) { }
    // ...
}
```

Then, decorate Double.DenseMatrix with:

```
[DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(MatrixSummary))]
```

### What I'd like to work

I'd prefer not having to implement a separate proxy for every type, so let's make it generic:

```
public class MatrixSummary<T> where T : ...
{
    public MatrixSummary(Matrix<T> matrix) { }
    // ...
}
```

Then, decorate Double.DenseMatrix with:

```
[DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(MatrixSummary<>))]
```

Or maybe closed with:

```
[DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(MatrixSummary<double>))]
```

And/or maybe also add that attribute to the base classes if needed.

None of these work e.g. when debugging Unit Tests, even though the documentation says it is supposed to work when declaring the attribute with an open generic type (i.e. `MatrixSummary<>`). After all it also works fine with `List<T>` etc.

Any ideas?

Related:

- [Diagnosing why DebuggerTypeProxy attributes are not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385388/diagnosing-why-debuggertypeproxy-attributes-are-not-working)
- [How can I have my DebuggerTypeProxy target class inherit from base proxies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12443513/how-can-i-have-my-debuggertypeproxy-target-class-inherit-from-base-proxies)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8eyd8zc.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make `MatrixSummary` a nested class:

```
[DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(Matrix<>.MatrixSummary))]
```

Comment: Clever idea, thanks! Unfortunately it didn't work for me either. Current Workaround: A non-generic interface implemented by Matrix<T>, and a matching proxy.

Comment: Hmmm... it does work for me. I have it on the base class (i.e. your `Generic.Matrix<T>`) and it trickles down to the inherited classes as well.

Comment: Weird, I still can't make it work. My proxy is essentially (child of Matrix<T>):
public class MatrixSummary {
   public MatrixSummary(Matrix<T> m) { P = xy; }
   public string P {get;set;}
}
and I've added the attribute exactly as above to Matrix<T>. Did you do anything else? I'm wondering whether some setting or tool like R# is interfering somehow. I'm on VS2012 Update 2, with R# 7.1.2.